# R: Extract distinct pattern from KeyValue list

Tags: r, key-value, data-science

I have a dataset which looks similar to:

```
quest<-data.frame(city=c("Atlanta","New York","Atlanta","Tampa"), key_value=c("rev=63;code=ATL;qty=1;zip=45987","rev=10.60|34;qty=1|2;zip=12686|12694;code=NY","code=ATL;rev=12;qty=1;zip=74268","rev=3|24|8;qty=1|6|3;code=TPA;zip=33684|36842|30254"))
```

which corresponds to:

```
    city                                           key_value
1  Atlanta                     rev=63;code=ATL;qty=1;zip=45987
2 New York        rev=10.60|34;qty=1|2;zip=12686|12694;code=NY
3  Atlanta                     code=ATL;rev=12;qty=1;zip=74268
4    Tampa rev=3|24|8;qty=1|6|3;code=TPA;zip=33684|36842|30254
```

I am trying to extract only one of the key value pattern ("code") out of the data which looks like the below:

```
      city code
1  Atlanta  ATL
2 New York   NY
3  Atlanta  ATL
4    Tampa  TPA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `strcapture` which returns the captured parts of regexes:

```
cbind(quest, 
   strcapture(
     "code=([^;]*)",
     quest$key_value,
     data.frame(code=character())))
```

the regex `"code=([^;]*)"` looks for the text `code=` and then captures everything that isn't a semicolon. The data frame argument specifies the name and type of the returned value. Here I use `cbind` to return a data frame with an extra column.

```
> cbind(quest, strcapture("code=([^;]*)",quest$key_value,data.frame(code=character())))
      city                                           key_value code
1  Atlanta                     rev=63;code=ATL;qty=1;zip=45987  ATL
2 New York        rev=10.60|34;qty=1|2;zip=12686|12694;code=NY   NY
3  Atlanta                     code=ATL;rev=12;qty=1;zip=74268  ATL
4    Tampa rev=3|24|8;qty=1|6|3;code=TPA;zip=33684|36842|30254  TPA
```

Answer (score 2):

We can do this with Regex using a positive lookbehind

```
quest$code <- gsub(".*(?<=code=)(\\w+)(;|$).*", "\\1", quest$key_value, perl = TRUE)
```

`.*` - Match up to our lookbehind

`(?<=code=)` - match the place in the string where the preceding characters are "code="

`(\\w+)` - match the code and capture it in group one.

`(;|$)` - match a semi-colon or the end of the string (in the case of NY there is no semi-colon afterwards)

`.*` - match the remainder of the string

```
      city                                           key_value code
1  Atlanta                     rev=63;code=ATL;qty=1;zip=45987  ATL
2 New York        rev=10.60|34;qty=1|2;zip=12686|12694;code=NY   NY
3  Atlanta                     code=ATL;rev=12;qty=1;zip=74268  ATL
4    Tampa rev=3|24|8;qty=1|6|3;code=TPA;zip=33684|36842|30254  TPA
```

Live example

https://regex101.com/r/UM7Cim/4